# splitting a large array into smaller arrays based on the key names

Tags: php

I have the array below which I need to split into smaller arrays based on the [location] key (so I'd like an array of .co.uk and an array of .com). The [location] key is not limited to .co.uk or .com.

Any help is appreciated.

```
[22] => Array
    (
        [query] => tttt
        [location] => .co.uk
        [x] => 1292889600
        [y] => 1
        [fullurl] => http://www.tttt.com/
    )

[20] => Array
    (
        [query] => tttt
        [location] => .co.uk
        [x] => 1292976000
        [y] => 1
        [fullurl] => http://www.tttt.com/
    )

[21] => Array
    (
        [query] => tttt
        [location] => .com
        [x] => 1292976000
        [y] => 1
        [fullurl] => http://www.tttt.com/
    )

[19] => Array
    (
        [query] => tttt
        [location] => .co.uk
        [x] => 1293062400
        [y] => 1
        [fullurl] => http://www.tttt.com/
    )

[18] => Array
    (
        [query] => tttt
        [location] => .com
        [x] => 1293062400
        [y] => 1
        [fullurl] => http://www.tttt.com/
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [query] => tttt
        [location] => .co.uk
        [x] => 1293148800
        [y] => 1
        [fullurl] => http://www.tttt.com/
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [query] => tttt
        [location] => .com
        [x] => 1293148800
        [y] => 1
        [fullurl] => http://www.tttt.com/
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [query] => tttt
        [location] => .com
        [x] => 1293235200
        [y] => 1
        [fullurl] => http://www.tttt.com/
    )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$byLocation = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $item) {
    if (!isset($byLocation[$item['location']])) {
        $byLocation[$item['location']] = array();
    }
    $byLocation[$item['location']][$key] = $item;
}
```

Then for example `$byLocation['.co.uk'][22]` is the first item of your original array. If you don’t want to maintain the original key, just omit it and use `[]` instead.

Comment: Works perfectly. had to change $byLocation[$item['location']][$key] = $val; to  $byLocation[$item['location']][$key] = $item; though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have thought you simply need to iterate over the array as follows:

1. Check to see if the current "location" is known (array_key_exists) in a $domains array. If it doesn't add it. (`$domains[<current key>] = array();`)
2. Add the current data as a new array under the relevant location key in the $domains array. (`array_push($domains[<current key>], array('query'=>XXX, 'x'=>...));`)