# Splitting arrays based on key sequence in php

Tags: php

I have some code which is used to split 1 array in to multiple arrays based on key sequence. I want the 1 array to split in to multiple arrays just like the below code.

This is the array,

```
$weekday_array = array(
 1 => 'Monday',
 2 => 'Tuesday',
 3 => 'Wednesday',
 5 => 'Friday',
 6 => 'Saturday'
 );
```

I want output like this,

```
$arr1 = array(
 1 => 'Monday'
 2 => 'Tuesday'
 3 => 'Wednesday'
);
$arr2 = array(
 5 => 'Friday',
 6 => 'Saturday'
)
```

Comment: And what is the rule which says where you want to make the split?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split Array into Smaller Arrays Based on Value of Key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382362/split-array-into-smaller-arrays-based-on-value-of-key)

Answer (score 1):

use **array_slice** with 4th parameter true or **array_chunk** with 3rd parameter true, according to your requirements

```
<?php
$weekdays = [
 1 => 'Monday',
 2 => 'Tuesday',
 3 => 'Wednesday',
 5 => 'Friday',
 6 => 'Saturday'
];

$weekdays_groups = array_chunk($weekdays, 3, true);

var_dump($weekdays_groups[0], $weekdays_groups[1]);
```

Comment: don't know why somebody voted down for this answer :D

Comment: It was not very detailed.. I'm glad you edited it though upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

What is the rule you need to make the split? The following code is **working for just your example**. You may have to change the code according to rule which you need.

```
<?php
$weekday_array = array(
 1 => 'Monday',
 2 => 'Tuesday',
 3 => 'Wednesday',
 5 => 'Friday',
 6 => 'Saturday'
 );

$new_array=array_chunk($weekday_array,3);

$arr1=$new_array[0];
$arr2=$new_array[1];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result=array(array());
for ($weekdays as $w)
{
    if ($a=='Wednesday')
         $result[]=array();
    $result[count($result)-1][]=$a;
}
```

Where `($a=='Wednesday')` should be replaced with your splitting criterion